# Why cant i run Jar file in Windows?

Tags: java, windows, javafx, java-runtime-compiler

I am trying to run a javaFx jar in windows cmd with java -jar filename.jar but i get this error:
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application.
In intellij works the programm fine but i cant run it in Windows. Any Ideas?

This is my Java Version

```
java version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.5+10-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.5+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Comment: *JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application* Kind of explains itself. You must include JFX into your classpath. Since version X JavaFX is not part of JRE

Comment: That happens if u use an openjdk instead of an oracle jdk. Open jdk does not contain java fx by default. And newer oracle ones dont as well...